# I have no sound in my Media players

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No sound in any media player](https://superuser.com/questions/375537/no-sound-in-any-media-player)

I have Windows Professional x64 with two sound cards.
for many months these cards (and the all sound system) was working fine.
Suddenly my System (my PC) stops having sound. from WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYERS and for any other media players
The default sounds from windows are working fine but I don't have sounds from media players.
Also I open the "Sounds And Audio Device Properties" and in "Volume"Tab I press "Advance".
 There I receive an error "DirectSoundSetting not available".
I have already Uninstall and re install my sound cards... But Nothing.
 
Did anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: As a diagnostic step, open a command prompt (`Run -> cmd`) then type `sc query audiosrv`. If the *STATE* field indicates *STOPPED*, then type `net start audiosrv` and see if it gives an error. If it starts without error, test your audio. If it works, then type `sc qc audiosrv` and see what the *START_TYPE* field says.

Comment: In the first command the STATE says RUNING, in the second command says AUTO_START....

Comment: That's too bad, it would have been an easy fix. Now we need to try to figure out what the problem is... It seems like maybe it is a hardware acceleration issue. The basic sounds are playing through software rendering (via the CPU), while the media players are trying to use the sound-card directly. Have you updated your drivers recently? Check your Windows Update log to see if it automatically installed a new driver (it does that sometimes).

Comment: It seems that you are not the only person with this problem: [No sound in any media player](http://superuser.com/questions/375537/no-sound-in-any-media-player)

Comment: Yes I have uninstall all the drivers for my sound cards and also I have uninstall every media player I have.. I also reinstall them and finally all the sounds (default) are working. Other sound programs are working fine. ONLY the medial players not working. And a game..

Comment: You *un*-installed them? Well you need to re-install the sound-card's drivers, otherwise direct access (acceleration) won't work and you will have to configure your media players to use the software rendering (e.g., "default sound device").

Comment: My friend of course I have reinstall them all and working fine.. But not them media players

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4067/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-synetech)